# Redirect url with query on a url with no query

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

We removed some old modules on our website and now google give us a lot of 404 error when he parse the website.

example :

```
best-sales.php?n=20&p=7
best-sales.php?n=10&p=39
best-sales.php?n=10&p=59
best-sales.php?n=20&p=32
...
```

I tried to redirect them to the index with htaccess and rewriterule like this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^n=20&p=7$
RewriteRule ^best-sales\.php$ /index.php [R=301,L]
```

but it always redirect to index.php?n=20&p=7 (with the old parameters)

Someone have an idea to redirect all pages like best-sales.php?XXXXXXXXXXXXX to index.php ?

Regards, 
Fred

Comment: http://viget.com/extend/no-query-string-no-problem -- if I understand correctly try adding a question mark to your target, i.e. `/index.php?`